# How to apply mutate and case_when to all columns in a df in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame `df` :

```
df <- structure(list(c1 = c(NA, 0.2, 0.3), c2 = c(0.7, 0.1, 0.6), 
    c3 = c(0.6, 0.6, 0.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
3L))

> df
   c1  c2  c3
1 NA  0.7 0.6
2 0.2 0.1 0.6
3 0.3 0.6 0.6
```

I want to mutate this df, so if the entry is above 0.5, it is replaced with "-".  Desired outcome:

```
> df
   c1  c2  c3
1 NA   -   -
2 0.2  0.1 -
3 0.3  -   -
```

I tried the following but I get an error message:

```
df <- df %>%
    mutate_all(~ case_when((.) > 0.05 ~ "-", TRUE ~ as.numeric(.)))

    Error: must be a character vector, not a double vector
```

What is the correct code to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have data of only one type in a column. Since `"-"` is not numeric you need to change the numbers to characters.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = ~case_when(. > 0.5 ~ "-", TRUE ~ as.character(.))))
  #with `mutate_all`
  #mutate_all(~case_when(. > 0.5 ~ "-", TRUE ~ as.character(.)))

#    c1  c2 c3
#1 <NA>   -  -
#2  0.2 0.1  -
#3  0.3   -  -
```

However, an easier solution is in base R :

```
df[df > 0.5] <- '-'
```